# How can I split a Qstring but the prompts are many in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qstring

For example:
I want to split my QString into 2 parts by the prompt "abc",but the "abc" in the QString is not only one (such as a QString = "123abc1234567890abc9876543210"),so how can I split it to "123abc" and "1234567890abc9876543210" but not "123abc1234567890abc" and "9876543210"?

(PS:use QStringList split)

Comment: And what's your splitting rule then if you don't want to split on every 'abc'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `QRegularExpression`  in this case. See [QRegularExpression::match](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qregularexpression.html#match) method.

To capture the strings you want, you need a regular expression like `(^[0-9]+(?>abc))|((?<=abc)\w+)` to be used as

```
QRegularExpression("(^[0-9]+(?>abc))|((?<=abc)\w+)").match("123abc1234567890abc9876543210")
```

> The returned QRegularExpressionMatch object contains the results of the match

To get a list of all strings captured by capturing groups you can use [QRegularExpressionMatch::capturedTexts()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qregularexpressionmatch.html#capturedTexts)

It should return the following strings in a list

```
123abc
1234567890abc9876543210
```

So finally your code would be like

```
QStringList strings = QRegularExpression("(^[0-9]+(?>abc))|((?<=abc)\w+)").match("123abc1234567890abc9876543210").capturedTexts();
```